# disable submit button according to at least 1/10 checkboxes being checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

The user are of the site I am working on has an email management section.
This displays a list of emails that they have Sent, Inactive, And In process

There are options that allow to select specific emails and send them or make them inactive, or active.

My problem is that if the user has no tick boxes checked, they can click one of these buttons and the jquery / ajax for this button is run, with nothing in.

I would like to stop this from happening and am not sure how to go about it for multiple checkboxes.

I found a solution that did what i want for 1 checkbox, not say, 10 for example. If one is clicked then another, it will disable the button again

```
    <div class='span8' style='padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:0px;'><label class='checkbox'><input title='Select All Sent Emails' type='checkbox' id='selectallsent'>Select All Sent</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class='checkbox'><input title='Select All In Progress Emails' type='checkbox' id='selectallprogress'>Select All In Progress</label><br /><label class='checkbox'><input title='Select All Active Emails' type='checkbox' id='selectallactive'>Select All Active</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class='checkbox'><input title='Select All Inactive Emails' type='checkbox' id='selectallinactive'>Select All In Inactive</label></div>
    <div class='span4' style='padding-bottom:10px;text-align:right;margin-right:0px;vertical-align:top;'><br /><br /><input type="button" onclick="inactive()" class="btn btn-small setInactive" value="Set Inactive">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" onclick="active()" class="btn btn-small setActive" value="Set Active">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#send_emails" type="button" onclick="sendResend()" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-small">Send / Resend</a></div></form>
    <table id='reviewHistoryTable' class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th align='center' width='2%'></th>
        <th align="center" width="10%">
        Order Id
        </th>
        <th align="center" width="20%">
        Customer Name
        </th>
        <th align="center" width="20%">
        Customer Email
        <th align="center" width="20%" >
        Date Send
    </th>
        <th align='center' width='5%'>
        Type
        </th>
        <th align="center" width="15%" >
        Status
        </th>
     </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <?php foreach($histories as $row): ?>

        <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='<?=$row->service_feedback_email_id?>' class='<?=$row->email_sent?> <?=$row->status?>'></td>
            <td ><?=$row->order_id?></td>
            <td ><?=$row->customer_name?> </td>
            <td ><?=$row->customer_email;?> </td>
            <td><?=$row->date_send;?> </td>
            <td><?=(!$row->review_type || $row->review_type=='store')?"Store":"Product"?></td>
            <td>
            <div id="editEmail_<?=$row->service_feedback_email_id?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editEmailLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3>Edit Details</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="height:900px;">

                <form name="editEmail" id="<?=$row->service_feedback_email_id?>" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?=$row->service_feedback_email_id?>" id="serviceFeedbackEmailId">
                    <label>Order ID</label><input id="orderId_<?=$row->service_feedback_email_id?>" type="text" value="<?=$row->order_id?>" disabled/>
                    <label>Customer Name</label><input id="customerName_<?=$row->service_feedback_email_id?>" class="customerName" name="customerName" type="text" value="<?=$row->customer_name?>"/>
                    <label>Customer Email</label><input id="customerEmail_<?=$row->service_feedback_email_id?>" type="text" value="<?=$row->customer_email?>"/>
                    <div class="input-prepend input-append">   
                        <input name="from_date" type="text" class='datepicker' value='<?=$row->date_send;?>'>
                        <span class="add-on"><i class=' icon-calendar'></i></span>
                    </div><br/>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" onclick="update()" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-small" value="Update">
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            </td>

        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>

    <div align='center'><?php echo($paging_link);?></div>
     <!--<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="buttons">
                   <!-- <form action="<?=site_url()?>admin/csvexport/exportexitclick" method="post" target="_blank">
                        <input type="hidden" id="query" name="query" value="<?php //echo($query);?>" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Export CSV" name="export-submit" id="export-submit" class="button fr ">

                        <!--<a id="exportcsv" class="button fr " href="" target="_blank">Export CSV</a>
                    </form>
                </div>        
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>-->   
<?php 
} 
?>
            <div id="send_emails" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sendEmailLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3>Send Emails</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="height:40px;">

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" onclick="send()" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-small" value="Send New Emails Only">
                <input type="button" onclick="resend()" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-small" value="Resend Old Emails Only">
                <input type="button" onclick="sendall()" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-small" value="Send / Resend All Selected Emails">
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</a>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
<script>
$('span[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    trigger: "hover",
    placement: "right"
});
var selected = new Array();

function sendResend() {
    var selected = Array();
    var selectedSend = $(".no:checked").length;
    var selectedResend = $(".yes:checked").length;
    var totalSendResend = selectedSend + selectedResend;
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    if (totalSendResend < 1) {
        $("#send_emails .modal-body").html('You have selected no emails. Please select some emails before proceeding.');
        $("#send_emails .modal-body").css({
            "height": "20px"
        });
    } else {
        $("#send_emails .modal-body").html('You have selected ' + totalSendResend + ' emails. ' + selectedSend + ' New emails will be sent & ' + selectedResend + ' will be resent. Please confirm that you want to proceed?');
    }
}

function send() {
    ajaxEmailQuery($(".no:checked"));
}

function resend() {
    ajaxEmailQuery($(".no:checked"));
}

function sendall() {
    ajaxEmailQuery($(".yes:checked"));
}

function ajaxEmailQuery(data) {
    var selected = Array();
    data.each(function () {
        selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/b2b/ajaxEmailQuery",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            data: selected
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            loadFeedbackServiceHistory(1)
        }
    })
}

function inactive() {
    var selected = Array();

    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to set these emails as inactive?');
    if (answer) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/b2b/inactive",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                data: selected
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                loadFeedbackServiceHistory(1)
            }
        })
    }
}

function active() {
    var selected = Array();

    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    var disabled = $(".setActive");
    if(selected>0){
        $disabled.removeProp("disabled");
    }        
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to set these emails as active?');
    if (answer) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/b2b/active",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                data: selected
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                loadFeedbackServiceHistory(1)
            }
        })
    }
}
$(function () {

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectallsent").click(function () {
        $('.yes').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $("#selectallprogress").click(function () {
        $('.no').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $("#selectallactive").click(function () {
        $('.active').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $("#selectallinactive").click(function () {
        $('.inactive').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".yes").click(function () {

        if ($(".yes").length == $(".yes:checked").length) {
            $("#selectallsent").prop("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectallsent").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
    $(".no").click(function () {

        if ($(".no").length == $(".no:checked").length) {
            $("#selectallprogress").prop("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectallprogress").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
    $(".active").click(function () {

        if ($(".active").length == $(".active:checked").length) {
            $("#selectallactive").prop("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectallactive").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
    $(".inactive").click(function () {

        if ($(".inactive").length == $(".inactive:checked").length) {
            $("#selectallinactive").prop("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectallinactive").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});

function update() {
    var id = $("#serviceFeedbackEmailId").val();
    var customerName = $("#customerName" + "_" + id).val();
    var customerEmail = $("#customerEmail" + "_" + id).val();
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to update this email? Changes can not be reverted.');
    if (answer) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/b2b/update",
            data: {
                id: id,
                customerName: customerName,
                customerEmail: customerEmail
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                loadFeedbackServiceHistory(1)
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
<!-- dashboard-content -->
```

Comment: Please try to re-format your code and put just the part that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a click listener to each checkbox and when a box is clicked the "submit" button is enabled!

Maybe not what you are looking for but it does the job!

An other option is to use a loop that goes over all the checkboxes. As soon as you encounter the first box that is checked you can stop the loop and continue processing the data.

edit:

Pseudo code:

```
for each (checkbox)
{
  var checked = checkbox.checked();
  if (checked)
  {
    submit();
    exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: in this code only the last checkbox in the loop will control the button event.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to create a solution using this jQuery `$("input:button").prop("disabled", "disabled");
function checkbox()
{
 var checkbox = $("input:checked").length;
 if(checkbox<1){
  $("input:button").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
 } else if(checkbox>0){
  $("input:button").removeAttr('disabled');
 }
}`

Answer (score 3):

Assign each email input a class such as `emailInput`.  This can be used to loop through all of the checkbox inputs using the JQuery `.each()` method.

You can use a `return` to break out of a `.each()` loop early.  [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

**Example**

```
$('#SendEmailsBtn' ).click(function () {
  //Loop through checkbox inputs
  $('.emailInput').each(function ( index, domEle) {
    // domEle == this
    //Check if input is checked
    if ($(domEle).is(":checked"))
    {
       SubmitFunction();
       return;  //At least one input is checked exit loop
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Malkus, I added a class to each of them just without adding jquery or anything and that makes the buttons not work at all. I'm currently still trying to figure this out, I dont think it helps that I lack a good deal of jQuery knowledge. But alas, I thanks you all for your help, in the meantime i'm going to do some more browsing on the interweb

Answer (score 2):

If at least one checkbox is checked, call the submit function, else do nothing.

```
$("#SendEmailBtn").click(function(){
    if ($("input:checked").length != 0)
       submit();
}
```